# @font-face da error cuando la utilizo en la hoja de estilos principal y la importo a la hoja de estilos de algún componente

Tags: css, angular, sass

Fichero global.scss (hoja de estilos principal):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Mermaid;
    src: url(./assets/fonts/mermaid.ttf);
}
```

Hoja de estilos de algún componente:

```
@import './../../global.scss';

.titulo {
   font-family: 'Mermaid', serif;
}
```

Mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, el error que te muestra es que está tratando de encontrar la fuente **./assets/fonts/** en el otro directorio que indica al final. Puedes mostrar la parte que está en rojo? puede que sea algo de llamar bien a la ruta donde tienes la fuente

Comment: Prueba con __src: url('./assets/fonts/mermaid.ttf') format('truetype');__